# flutter: how to use type or generic to Map?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
class TestModel {
  String? firstName, lastName;
  TestModel(this.firstName, this.lastName);

  TestModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : firstName = json['firstName'],
        lastName = json['lastName'];
        
}
```

I get that I can convert incoming json to `TestModel`. However, how can I assign `TestModel` type to a variable `Map`?

```
TestModel a = {'firstName': 'huh', 'lastName': 'whaaat!?'} as TestModel;
```

`TestModel a` or `Map<TestModel>` does not work, while

```
var a = {'firstName': 'huh', 'lastName': 'whaaat!?'};
print(TestModel.fromJson(a));
```

This works. How can I directly assign the model to the variable without using `.fromJson`, because I am directly getting the values from the `TextField`?

Comment: Why can't you use `.fromJson`? Won't `TestModel a = TestModel.fromJson({'firstName': 'huh', 'lastName': 'whaaat!?'});` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just can initialize it, for example:

```
TestModel a = TestModel('huh', 'whaaat!?');
```